# Cypress integration with asciidoc (asciidoctor)

Tags: cypress, asciidoc, asciidoctor

is thre any way to work integrate asciidoctor (asciidoc) into cypress and creating tests using both? If yes, could you please explane how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Cypress is a browser-based test suite. Browsers don't natively process Asciidoc, but you can transform Asciidoc to HTML using `asciidoctor.js`, and `asciidoctor.js` can run in a browser.

So, you could write a Cypress test that confirmed whether the use of `asciidoctor.js` performed the desired transformation as expected.

How you get the Asciidoc markup into the browser is up to you. It could be embedded in the page, it could be fetched with an AJAX or JSONP request, it could be provided as a query string parameter.